# what the difference between NSBundle and CFbundle?

Tags: ios

```
 NSBundle* mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
```

I know we can use the above to get the mainBundle

But I saw someone use

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
```

Is there any difference between those two?

Answer (score 1):

`NSBundle` and `CFBundleRef` are not toll-free bridged to each other so you couldn't say they were identical, but they both do the same job and offer the same features. Which you use should only be driven by how you are going to use it in the current code.

Answer (score 0):

Wain is correct, these are not toll-free bridged to each other.

The Cocoa documentation describes the difference in more detail ([CFBundle and NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/CFNSBundle.html), emphasis added):

> **Most of [NSBundle's] methods invoke the corresponding CFBundle routines and are modeled after them**. Note, however, that pointers to NSBundle objects cannot be cast to CFBundleRefs, unlike some other Core Foundation types and Foundation equivalents—**they are not toll-free bridged**.
>
> **For most of its methods, NSBundle simply calls the appropriate CFBundle routine to do its work**, but **loading code is different**. Because CFBundle does not handle Objective-C symbols, NSBundle has to use a different mechanism for loading code. NSBundle interacts with the Objective-C runtime system to correctly load and register all Cocoa classes and other executable code in the bundle executable file.
>
> At the very least, Cocoa bundles contain a single class, the principal class, which serves as an entry point into a bundle. See Loadable Bundles in Cocoa for a discussion of the principal class.
>
> Because of a limitation in the Objective-C runtime system, NSBundle cannot unload executable code. Since CFBundle does not know about Objective-C symbols, do not use the CFBundle loading and unloading routines on NSBundle objects. You can, however, create a CFBundle object for a Cocoa bundle and use the other routines—unrelated to loading and unloading—without trouble.